# How to prevent endless loop in react and socket.io

Tags: javascript, reactjs, socket.io

Hello i'm building a realtime chat messenger. 
It works like this, but it creates an endless loop and opens thousands of sockets.

I've tried to build an array and push to that and then return it, but then my chat does not update when i send a message.

Can someone please help?

Thanks in advance!

```
import React from 'react';

export default function useGetChatMessages(_id) {
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io('http://localhost:9090');
    socket.emit('send-chat-id', _id);
    socket.on('chat-messages', data => {
      setChatMessages(data.messages);
    });
    socket.on('new-chat-message', message => {
      chatMessages.push(message);
    });
  }, [_id, chatMessages]);

  return chatMessages;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `chatMessages` changes you create another socket, and add all the event handlers, which changes `chatMessages`, and so on.

Don't make `chatMessages` a dependency of `useEffect`, use an [updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates) with `setChatMessages` to get the current value of `chatMessages`, and create a new array with the new message.

**Note:** don't mutate state in React (using push for example), create a new array, as you can see in the `new-chat-message` handler.

```
export default function useGetChatMessages(_id) {
  const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const io = require('socket.io-client');
    const socket = io('http://localhost:9090');
    socket.emit('send-chat-id', _id);
    socket.on('chat-messages', data => {
      setChatMessages(data.messages);
    });
    socket.on('new-chat-message', message => {
      setChatMessages(messages => [...messages, message]); // updater function
    });
  }, [_id]);

  return chatMessages;
}
```

Comment: Oh yes. exactly what i was looking for! :-) thanks for the explanation! i knew it must have to do something with the magic three dots.

Answer (score 1):

- Connect to socket io only one time. Put it outside mounted component for best practice.
- Do not listen every time you get new message. Listen only 1 time, so delete your update for incoming new messages.

Like this:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import io from 'socket.io-client'
    const socket = io('http://localhost:9090')

    export default function useGetChatMessages(_id) {
      const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = React.useState([]);

      React.useEffect(() => {
        socket.emit('send-chat-id', _id);
        socket.on('chat-messages', data => {
          setChatMessages(data.messages);
        });
        socket.on('new-chat-message', message => setChatMessages([...chatMessages, message]));
      }, [_id]);

      return chatMessages;
    }
```